# Express-Validator: Validation Error Message not Appearing for custom validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

If I try to register a duplicate user Name, it all works, except for the error message saying it has already been registered.  All the other error messages work; just not this one.

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
var name = req.body.name;
var email = req.body.email;
// var username = req.body.username;
var username = req.body.name;
var password = req.body.password;
var password2 = req.body.password2;

req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('name', 'This name is already registered.')
.custom(function(name, req){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findOne({ name: name }, (err, user) => {
            console.log(name);
            console.log(user);
            if (err) throw err;
            if(user == null) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                console.log('rejecting');
                reject();
            }
        });
    });
}); 

req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
// req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
    res.render('register',{
        errors:errors
    });
} else {
    var newUser = new User({
        name: name,
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure the way you chain `custom()` in your code is for the new API only. You are otherwise using the legacy API. For the legacy API you have to define the custom validators when you apply the middleware (in app.js or something similar). For example:

```
app.use(expressValidator({
  customValidators: {
    isUniqueName: function(name) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findOne({ name: name }, (err, user) => {
          console.log(name);
          console.log(user);
          if (err) throw err;
          if (user == null) {
            resolve();
          } else {
            console.log('rejecting');
            reject();
          }
        });
      });
    },
  },
}));
```

and in the controller:

```
req.checkBody('name', 'This name is already registered.').isUniqueName();
```

I would generally recommend changing to the new API. It shouldn't take too much time when you already know what you want to validate. It's written more about that [here](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator).

Comment: I just installed the package 3 days ago.  My package.json file contains: "express-validator": "*",

Comment: @Jeff Matthews You can use the legacy API with the newest version. It supports both the legacy and new API. The express-validator readme recommends changing to the new API because the legacy API might be removed in the future.

Comment: I am not understanding.  Typing "npm list express-validator" returns `-- express-validator@4.3.0  Doesn't this mean I am using the latest, and isn't my code sample for use with the latest?  I don't see what legacy has to do with anything.

Comment: OK.  I found the documentation and am reading about legacy, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It was a good read.  FYI, I also failed to realize there was an async version of validateErrors() called... asyncValidateErrors().  After revisions, the code is working fine, now.